# jQuery on() click firing twice, trying to narrow the focus results in incorrect action

Tags: jquery

Hopefully I can explain this properly.

I've got an HTML table full of items. Each item is a clickable link that launches a modal to edit that item. My code as it is currently causes the action to fire twice, but the second time does not contain the complete parameters. Trying to narrow the focus to prevent 'bubbling up' (if I'm understanding it correctly) causes it to fire once but also with incomplete parameters.

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="span12">
<table class='table table-condensed table-bordered'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="span4">
                <a href="#" id="listingEditModal00000011643" listing_id="00000011643" user_sub="false">Example 1</a>
            </td>
            <td class="center"></td>
            <td>
                Oct 18th 2013 - 8:00 pm
            </td>
            <td>
                Example 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Example 1
            </td>
            <td>
                3.50
            </td>
            <td>
                Delete
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="span4">
                <a href="#" id="listingEditModal00000011784" listing_id="00000011784" user_sub="false">Example 2</a>
            </td>
            <td class="center"></td>
            <td>
                Oct 5th 2013 - 6:00 pm
            </td>
            <td>
                Example 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Example 2
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                Delete
            </td>
        </tr>

        ...

    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#content').on('click', "[id^=listingEditModal]", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('listing_id');
    var user_sub = $(this).attr('user_sub');
    var val = '/AdminListings/edit/' + id + '?user_sub=' + user_sub;
    $('#addItemBody').load(val);
    $('#addItemModal').modal({});
});
```

The above fires twice according to firebug:

```
GET http://example.com/AdminListings/edit/00000011643?user_sub=false 200 OK 366ms

GET http://example.com/AdminListings/edit/00000011643 200 OK 342ms
```

With the second one being used in the modal (i.e. the user_sub parameter is not passed)

If I modify the jQuery as such:

```
$('#content').on('click', "[id^=listingEditModal] > td", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('listing_id');
    var user_sub = $(this).attr('user_sub');
    var val = '/AdminListings/edit/' + id + '?user_sub=' + user_sub;
    $('#addItemBody').load(val);
    $('#addItemModal').modal({});
});
```

It only fires once, and does not include the user_sub parameter.

```
GET http://example.com/AdminListings/edit/00000011643 200 OK 502ms
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The HTML in which it 'works once' has a more specific selector, which suggests that you've got two elements (one within the other) that *both* match the `[id^="..."]` selector. *That's* the problem; select the parent (or the child) but not both. Without seeing your HTML (and the snippet you provided is not enough to reproduce your problem), I can't offer specific advice.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to change your function to start `function(e) { e.preventDefault();`, to stop the default click behaviour on the links. Also your html has an extra `"` just before `user_sub="...`.

Comment: @david-thomas I've updated the HTML to show a more complete picture of the content. I have multiple rows with links where id begins with 'listingEditModal'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you must, use stopImmediatePropagation:

```js
$('#content').on('click', "[id^=listingEditModal]", function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this will prevent further bubbling
  e.preventDefault(); // since it's a link, you should stop it from firing
  var id = $(this).attr('listing_id');
  var user_sub = $(this).attr('user_sub');
  var val = '/AdminListings/edit/' + id + '?user_sub=' + user_sub;
  $('#addItemBody').load(val);
  $('#addItemModal').modal({});
});
```

but that doesn't appear to be the problem. there's another similar event that is firing the `$('#addItemBody').load(val);`. Have you double checked if there isn't another click, like a `'click', 'td'` for example?

Comment: _"this will prevent bubbling"_ - It will prevent _further_ bubbling, noting that the event is currently being handled after it has already bubbled up to whatever element `#content` is.

Comment: he posted only a part of the code. my bet is that there's another event listening for a `click` event that is receiving a propagated event from the anchor click

Comment: @pocesar This has solved it for me, it's now firing once and including the desired parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try changing

```
$('#content').on('click', "[id^=listingEditModal]", function () {
```

to

```
$('#listingEditModal').on('click', function () {
```

Also to note there is no td within your id="listEditModal"

"[id^=listingEditModal] > td"

Comment: The OP's code used the attribute starts with selector `[id^=...]` for a reason - your suggestion changes the selector to an id that isn't present...